# Find avg of each row from the grand total

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, average

I have a sales table `sale` with following columns

sale_id | Department | gross_amount

I need to find the avg of sales in each department from the total sale

eg:- 
**Table**

```
sale_id     Department     gross_amount
  1            A             10
  2            B             30
  3            A             25
  4            c              5

Desired output

Department               Gross_amount     avg
  A                          35            50       --(35/70)*100
  B                          30            42.86    --(30/70)*100
  C                          5             7.14     --(5/70) *100
```

ie is dept_avg = (dept_total / total) *100
eg:- dept_total of A = 35
     total = A+B+C = 35+30+5 =70

I am able to find up to Gross_amount

```
select Department ,sum(si.GrossPrice)  gross_amt
from Sale si
group by Department 
order by Department
```

For getting avg I tried follow

```
 select Department ,sum(si.GrossPrice) gross_amt,
    AVG(sum(si.GrossPrice)) avg
    from Sale si
    group by Department 
    order by Department
```

It is giving me an error

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

Also I am not sure i can get my expected avergage with the above query. How can I achieve the same.

Comment: Can you correct your question to use the same column names where they are identical, and explain why you divide by 100 all the time?

Comment: @Amit i edited my question..divison by 100.0 is doing to get two decimal point in the answer...i removed that to avoid confusion

Comment: Sachu, please don't rush anything. Take your time, and decide: gross_amount, Gross_amount or GrossPrice? dept_avg or avg? what is dept_total? what is total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide grouped sum by total sum:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2624b/6/0)**

```
SELECT Department ,
     [Gross_amount] = SUM(gross_amount),
     [avg] = ROUND(CAST(SUM(gross_amount) AS DECIMAL(10,2))/
                   CAST((SELECT SUM(gross_amount) FROM tab) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * 100
             ,2)
FROM tab
GROUP BY Department 
ORDER BY Department
```

Comment: fiddle is working fine as my desired output..but when i apply on my table i am getting `Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.` error

Comment: @Sachu Change to `DECIMAL(10, 2)` and retry. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the proportion of the total for each department out of the overall total, I would suggest using window functions:

```
SELECT Department, SUM(gross_amount) as gross_amount
       SUM(gross_amount)*100.0 / SUM(SUM(gross_amount)) over () as propotion
FROM tab
GROUP BY Department 
ORDER BY Department;
```

Comment: gud suggestion but I am not able to use round or Convert(Decimal(10,2) with window over function.it is giving error

Comment: @Sachu . . . That should be irrelevant.  You probably have an error in your syntax.